# how to start postgres prior to run docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am super embarrassed to ask this question, because it seems a very basic one, but somehow I can't find the answer in docs.

I have a django app that uses postgres. In `docker-compose.yaml` there is the following requirement:

```
version: "2"

services:

database:
  image: postgres:9.5
  environment:
    POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DATABASE}
    POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    POSTGRES_DATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
```

when I run my docker image:
`docker run -it --name myapp myimage`
it keeps repeating:

```
The database is not ready.
wait for postgres to start...
```

I ran postgres in detached mode: `docker run -it -d postgres:9.5`
but it does not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at this [doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/).

Second example is exacly what you need:

You create sh script and add it to your app container by using `ADD` or `COPY`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# wait-for-postgres.sh

set -e

host="$1"
shift
cmd="$@"

until psql -h "$host" -U "postgres" -c '\l'; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done

>&2 echo "Postgres is up - executing command"
exec $cmd
```

Then you modify your docker-compose.yaml like this:

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    command: ["./wait-for-postgres.sh", "db", "python", "app.py"]
  db:
    image: postgres
```

In `command` you're orerriding default command of your container.
Of course `"python", "app.py"` part is depedent on how you start your app.
 Fo Java it would be for example `"java", "-jar", "my-app.jar"` etc.

Comment: but it tells me that the role 'my_user_name' is not found. In db: section I have now:
database:
    image: postgres:9.5
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "django_db"
      POSTGRES_USER: "my_user_name"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "my_password"
I should somehow 'tell' ti postgres image to create `my_user_name` user, right? But how?

Comment: Please check this [page](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/). You can set admin credentials by setting environment variables like `POSTGRES_PASSWORD`. You can check how to set env variables in docker-compose [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#substituting-environment-variables-in-compose-files).

Answer (score 3):

With Docker Compose 2.1 syntax, you can specify [healthchecks](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck) to control container start-up:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
    application:
        depends_on:
            database:
                condition: service_healthy
```

Check out https://github.com/docker-library/healthcheck/tree/master/postgres for an example Dockerfile for building Postgres with healthchecks.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is OK with the way you start the container, however, the issues you are experiencing it is because the DB and the APP containers are starting one after the other, however, the DB container, needs to prepare the DB, do the migrations and so on, so therefore, by the time your app container tries to reach your DB container it is not ready so that's why you are getting this error.

You have 2 choices, one is to edit your APP Dockerfile and add WAIT for 30 - 60 s or so, or you could just start the DB on its own, wait for it to be ready to go and then start your APP container.